# Plotting line chart from a pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have generated a pivot table like this!

```
df3=df1.pivot_table(index=['Sales promotion'],values=['Total recharge value'],aggfunc='sum')
df3
```

Result is this:

```
Total recharge value  Sales promotion
     Promo 1             583782.5000
     Promo 2             785754.1900
     Promo 3             562796.7800
     Promo 4             527441.3000
     Promo 5             749915.5096
```

Now I need to plot a line graph from this.

I have tried:

```
df3.plot(x='Sales promotion', y='Total recharge value', kind='line')
```

But it gives a `KeyError: 'Sales promotion'`

Please help!